# Count non blank cells above a cell until first blank

Tags: excel-formula

how do I count how many non blank cells until the first blank above a cell.

For example, it is 6 non blank cells from C15 to C6 until there is a blank cell C9. The array formula I know =Match(1,--(C5:C16=""),0)-1, always start counting from C5. Is there way to start backwards, like start counting from C16?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozXL7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MATCH` use `MAX`: `=MAX((C$5:C16="")*(ROW(C$5:C16))'.

Note, I used the Range you used in your example and locked the row at `C$5` by using `$`-sign. That way it will not change if you drag down the formula.

This formula will return the ROW # of the condition met. If used in combination with `INDEX` I recommend referencing the whole column, like so:
`=INDEX(C:C,MAX((C$5:C16="")*(ROW(C$5:C16)))'
I noticed you substracted 1 of the row. You can do the same after this formula.

Comment: thanks. but I don't want to know the row # of the condition met. I want to know how many rows when the condition met. thanks.

Comment: I think what you really mean is get all results, instead of getting the first and last. In that case use `LARGE` or `SMALL` instead of `MAX`